Display some order details on WooCommerce 3rd party plugin email template
I have inherited a PDF voucher plugin and would like to fetch and display custom order data in the woocommerce email template. This is the original email code.  I would like to display the customer billing first name.
<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_email_header', $email_heading, $email ); ?>
<p><?php printf( _n( "Hi there. You've been sent a voucher!", "Hi there. You've been sent %d vouchers!", $voucher_count, 'woocommerce-pdf-product-vouchers' ), $voucher_count ); ?></p>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_email_footer', $email ); ?>

Having a look through the developer documentation, we should be able to query the order object using $voucher->get_order(). I've tried with that and the following,  but it's returning nothing.
$order    = wc_get_order( $order_id );
$first_name = $order->get_billing_first_name();
echo $first_name;

and I tried:
<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_email_header', $email_heading, $email ); 
  $order = $email->object;
  $first_name = $order->get_billing_first_name; 
    echo $first_name;    
?>

What am I missing?

On WooCommerce PDF Product Vouchers plugin voucher-recipient.php template file, you can see:
/**
 * Voucher recipient html email
 *
 * @type \WC_Order $order the order object associated with this email
 * @type string $email_heading the configurable email heading
 * @type int $voucher_count the number of vouchers being attached
 * @type string $message optional customer-supplied message to display
 * @type string $recipient_name optional customer-supplied recipient name
 * @type \WC_PDF_Product_Vouchers_Email_Voucher_Recipient $email the email being sent
 *
 * @version 3.5.3
 * @since 1.2
 */

Which means that the WC_Order object $order is already available in this template.
So first, copy this template file in your child theme, inside a "woocommerce" folder > "emails" subfolder, to be able to override it.

Once done, open edit the copied file, and replace the line:
<p><?php printf( _n( "Hi there. You've been sent a voucher!", "Hi there. You've been sent %d vouchers!", $voucher_count, 'woocommerce-pdf-product-vouchers' ), $voucher_count ); ?></p>

with:
<p><?php printf( __("Hi %s. ", 'woocommerce-pdf-product-vouchers'), $order->get_billing_first_name() ) . printf( _n( "You've been sent a voucher!", "You've been sent %d vouchers!", $voucher_count, 'woocommerce-pdf-product-vouchers' ), $voucher_count ); ?></p>

Save. It should now display the customer first name.
